# Case within join's "ON" caluse

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-statement

I'm trying to do something like this...

```
SELECT lc.Location, count(h.empID) as 'Count', lu.LBL
FROM swam.lookup lu
    LEFT JOIN swam.empTable h
    ON CASE
        WHEN lu.sac is null 
            THEN lu.POS = h.POS
        ELSE (
            lu.POS = h.POS
            and
            lu.sac = h.sac)
    INNER JOIN swam.Locations lc
        ON h.LocationID = lc.LocationID
GROUP BY lc.Location, lu.LBL
ORDER BY lc.Location
```

So, if lu.sac is null, then only join the tables on one common column.
If it's not null, then it has to use both POS and SAC to join.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `case`.  Just use direct boolean logic:

```
FROM swam.lookup lu LEFT JOIN
     swam.empTable h
     ON lu.POS = h.POS AND
        (lu.sac is null OR lu.sac = h.sac) INNER JOIN
     swam.Locations fs
     ON h.LocationID = lc.LocationID
```

As a bonus, the database engine can also table advantage of an index on `pos` in either (or both) tables.

Comment: Is there any performance degradation when we put OR condition in Join or Where Condition in SQL Server i.e. non-sargable query? Refer below link :- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: @RGS . . . If the query would otherwise use indexes, then there is likely to be a performance degradation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT lc.Location, count(h.empID) as 'Count', lu.LBL
FROM swam.lookup lu
    LEFT JOIN swam.empTable h
    ON  (lu.sac is null  AND lu.POS = h.POS) OR  
                   not(lu.sac is null)  AND lu.POS = h.POS   and lu.sac = h.sac
    INNER JOIN swam.Locations fs
        ON h.LocationID = lc.LocationID
GROUP BY lc.Location, lu.LBL
ORDER BY lc.Location
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT lc.Location, count(h.empID) as 'Count', lu.LBL
FROM swam.lookup lu
LEFT JOIN swam.empTable h
  ON lu.POS = h.POS
 AND isnull(lu.sac, h.sac) = h.sac    
INNER JOIN swam.Locations fs
   ON h.LocationID = lc.LocationID  // this looks wrong lc is not defined
GROUP BY lc.Location, lu.LBL
ORDER BY lc.Location
```

and I think that last join will turn the left join intro and inner join

Comment: my bad, lc is supposed to be lu

Comment: my bad. fs should have been lc